# What are the effects of aging and health?

Tags: sid-meiers-pirates

My captain's been slowing down in combat lately, I assume this has got something to do that he is now 39 years old and in poor health. What effects do age and health have? Can I improve my health or mitigate the effects of aging somehow?

Answer (score 2):

Health affects the speed of your attacks and the speed of completing dance moves.

In order to slow the aging process you can buy mystical spices and herbs from the Mysterious Traveler in taverns.

The game ends when you divide the plunder at age 50.

Comment: Dance moves? Pretty sure those depend on the actual dance, I've certainly never seen my character to fall behind or get ahead of the other dancers. Isn't the age when you're forced to retire when dividing plunder dependant on health and therefore health-improving items? How much do items improve your health? Are they retroactive?

Comment: @kotekzot since there isn't a definitive guide out there about anti-aging items, and trying to come up with that information would take months this is all I have to offer.

Answer (score 2):

The best choice to help prevent this (too late if you've already progressed in the game, but for next time) is to select the "*Skill at Medicine*" when creating your character. This basically reduces the rate at which you age and lose various speed in skills. The screenshot below may not look like your version depending on platform.

[image: Pirates character creation screen]

The other thing is to prevent getting captured (by losing swordfights or sieges) because you "rot in a jail cell" which causes you to age, and reduces your health. I use save games effectively to prevent this if my skill isn't high enough.